# Prevent tooltip from overflowing without changing position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
.card-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-content:hover .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>This is the main content of the card.</p>
      <span class="tooltip">Hover over me to see the tooltip!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    </br>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>This is the main content of the card.</p>
      <span class="tooltip">Hover over me to see the tooltip!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a list of cards inside a container that has overflow hidden. I wish to present the tooltip over of the container without changing the size of the container or position of the tooltip.

Comment: I think there are libraries that do this by removing tooltip markup from the container and placing it in the `<body>` using javascript. They then position it with css using Javascript. E.G Bootstrap's `container` option https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#options

Comment: In your example, there is no room for the tooltip on the left or the right, so it has to be above or below. So why not make your code display the tooltip below, except for the last card where it should appear above?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<style>
.card-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card-content {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.tooltip {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.card-content:hover .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.9;
  backgound-color:black;
}
.tooltip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

</style>
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <p class="has-tooltip">This is the main content of the card.</p>
      <span class="tooltip-wrapper"><span class="tooltip">Hover over me to see the tooltip!</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
    </br>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <p class="has-tooltip">This is the main content of the card.</p>
       <span class="tooltip-wrapper"><span class="tooltip">Hover over me to see the tooltip!</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

This can be done by adding a new wrapper which is absolutely positioned and inside that the tooltip which is relatively positioned.